# Anaconda: Install local binary package to conda environment in Windows

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, cx-oracle

I need to install cx_Oracle, and when I open up the .exe, it doesn't find my conda installation because it isn't in the registry. How do I...

1. Add to registry or
2. Specify a path

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant registry key is in (python 2.7 on windows xp, others version might be similar) **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7\InstallPath** (if it is not there, create the key). Change it so that the anaconda `Python` is the default `python` installation.

(If you are using Python 3.x version, change the 2.7 version part)

Then you just run that exe installer of cx_Oracle. Then the installer should be able to locate python installation from registry.

---

*2018 EDIT*:

Now you can save all the trouble by installing the dependency from conda channel directly, not only the `cx_oralce` package, but Oracle driver (instant client) as well:

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/cx_oracle

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/oracle-instantclient

Please pay attention to the version number of instant client (11.x or 12.x) version.  It need to match the version of Oracle you are trying to access.